# Powershell query- Could not find a part of the path

Tags: powershell, csv, email, filepath

I am trying to work on a power shell script to query email id's from a csv list and send out bulk personalized emails.Both the csv file and the script are located on the desktop in the same folder(\DECSRV02\Folder Redirection\paranjyoti\Desktop\Powershell_massemail).
The script contains the csv import as :

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\paranjyoti\Desktop\Powershell_massemail\UserList.csv'
$Credential = Get-Credential
Foreach($Message in $csv){
$Recipient = $Message.EmailAddress
$FirstName = $Message.FirstName
$LastName = $Message.Surname
$Course = $Message.Course
$Grade = $Message.Grade
$Subject = "$FirstName $LastName - $Course Exam Result"
Write-Host "Sending email to $FirstName $LastName"
Write-Host "Email Address: $Recipient"
$mailBody = 
@"
Hello $FirstName,</br>
We have marked your recent exam and the results are as follows:</br>
</br>
Student Name: $LastName, $FirstName</br>
Course: $Course</br>
Result: $Grade</br>
</br>
Thank you for taking a course at our school,</br>
The Faculty
"@

Send-MailMessage -Body $mailBody -BodyAsHtml `
-From "faculty@greatschool.com" -To $Recipient `
-Subject $subject -Encoding $([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) `
-Credential $Credential -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -UseSSLcopy
}
```

While running the script, the error comes up as "Could not find a part of the path"
[The attached error message image is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx3RA.png)
Please can you help in identifying the error.

Comment: Please share relevant part of the script.

Comment: To expand on Gulshan's comment; please show us where the script is calling for that csv file. Also, you're saying the script and folder are in the same location, but you have two different paths in the image and your post.

Comment: Looking at the error you are getting the path "C:\Users\paranjyoti\Desktop\Powershell_massemail\UserList.csv" may not exist as you are using folder redirection to a network path for your desktop. I would suggest changing the path you are using to "\\DECSRV02\Folder Redirection\paranjyoti\Desktop\Powershell_massemail\UserList.csv" as this is the location of which your desktop folder resides physically.

Comment: Thanks, Theo. Just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows your desktop path has been redirected.
In order to get the path, you can use the registry:

```
$desktop = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders').Desktop
$csvPath = Join-Path -Path $desktop -ChildPath 'Powershell_massemail\UserList.csv'
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath
```

May I also suggest you use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) for the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet to get rid of those nasty backticks and make the code more readable:

```
$mailParams = @{
    Body       = $mailBody
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    Subject    = $subject
    Encoding   = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
    Credential = $Credential
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
    UseSsl     = $true
}

Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much.  I used the file path as:  $csv = Import-Csv -Path .\UserList.csv

Comment: It's best to avoid looking up special folders in the registry; I suggest using `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')`. From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031103-00/?p=41973: " Now there are those of you who are licking your lips and saying,“Wow, there’s this ‘User Shell Folders’ key that’s even cooler than the ‘Shell Folders’ key, let me go check it out.” I implore you to exercise restraint and not rely on this new key. Just use the function SHGetFolderPath, which returns the path to whatever folder you want. Let the “User Shell Folders” key rest in peace. "

Answer (score 4):

I got the error as below and even though it is not the exact answer to the question above I would share it here for anyone who for a similar issue.

> Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path
> "D:\projects\changeDetection\cubeRepos\cm-2.0\ConceptMiner2\CM.Spidering.CsSched
> uleLightweight\csx\Debug\roles\CM.Spidering.CsScheduleLightweight.Worker\approot\Templates\TEST\TEST\REG\TEST--TEST--REG--CACH
> E-REFRESH\TEST--TEST--REG--CACHE-REFRESH.structure.json".

But I verified that the above-mentioned folder path exists and the file can be created in the desired directory. A bit of googling got the real cause of the issue. It is because windows have a limitation of **260 characters** for the *file path*.
You would notice that my path has exactly *260 characters* but there is a small catch in path length validation. Path has a null character appended at the end of the path. So the total **path length becomes 261** which cause it to fail.

The quickest fix would be to **rename the file** so the new file name has less than 260 characters. More information about this error and ways to extend the path limits can be found in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to check the existence of the actual path?

I get the same error, because I don't have the folder structure:

```
PS C:\temp\csvimport> .\csvimport.ps1
Import-Csv : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\paranjyoti\Desktop\Powershell_massemail\UserList.csv'.
At C:\temp\csvimport\csvimport.ps1:1 char:8
+ $csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\paranjyoti\Desktop\Powershell_massemail\U ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

But it's a different error if it just can't find the file:

```
PS C:\temp\csvimport> .\csvimport.ps1
Import-Csv : Could not find file 'C:\userlist.csv'.
At C:\temp\csvimport\csvimport.ps1:1 char:8
+ $csv = Import-Csv 'C:\userlist.csv'
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

Not sure which part of the path is incorrect or missing.  That exercise is left to the reader.  ;)