# "Could not find part of the Path" Error Powershell. even though the path exists

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get all the Children of my File.
When I run the following piece of code:

```
#taking the input of the user!
$pathInputByUser= Read-Host ("Please Enter the Path!")

#Entering the path entered by the user
cd $pathInputByUser

#getting all the files and folders from our path
$AllFilesAndFolders= ( Get-ChildItem  -Recurse -File );
```

A few minutes after I run this code, I get the error described in the title:
"A part of the path  could not be found" even though it obviously exists.

How can I solve this problem so that I can get all the children?

**Guess 1 :**
One of the answers [in this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197788/powershell-query-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path) links suggests that the name of the path is simply too large for windows since windows has some limit of 260 character.
to solve this

- one can simply change the names of the folders [not possible in my case since the file
  structure belongs to another company]
- The "\?" prefix can be perhaps appended before the path and then it could work [didnt work in my case, my path starts with "//" already perhaps thats why it doesnt work.
- Anywho, the person had linked [a microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd) and perhaps you guys might understand something more than me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How does a path entered by the user look like? Is a folder? an absolute path? a UNC path? a relative path?

Comment: it looks something like //<nameofNetwork/<name of Folder on network>/<name of subfolder>

Comment: A UNC path uses backslashes not forward slashes.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon 
yes you are right, I made a typing mistake.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i meant \\<nameofNetwork/<name of Folder on network>/<name of subfolder>

Comment: I think you used to be able to map a drive to a folder to cut down on path length. Is that still a thing?